# in Facebook API /me/events fails to get events that you have not responded to. why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

in Facebook API /me/events fails to get events that you have not responded to. why?

Only events where I have clicked: maybe/no/yes does it show up in the graph api. How can I get these events that I have not responded to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve information about the events that a user has been invited to, but not responded to, using an FQL query like this:

```
SELECT eid,name,description,start_time,end_time,venue 
    FROM event 
    WHERE eid 
    IN (
        SELECT eid 
            FROM event_member 
            WHERE uid=me() 
            AND rsvp_status='not_replied'
       )
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually you can access the events you have received but not replied with this url (assuming you got the "user_events" permission):
    https://graph.facebook.com/me/events/not_replied

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the docs, it seems that it's not possible to get the events that have not been flagged by the user.

> Events: The events this user is attending

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/